# How to fix warning 'can't find referenced class' in Android Eclipse ProGuard Rule?

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am using Eclipse. In my Android code, I have used ProGuard. But while exporting the APK, I encountered the following warnings:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Warning: okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class     org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: there were 14 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 8):

You can Solve that by modifying the 'progaurd-rules.pro' which seems that you are using Progaurd for Shrinking your Code.

You must use `-dontwarn` But be careful before adding this to `proguard` file as there will not be errors at testing because `Proguard` had already delete some classes not being used

for case of OKiO add these lines

```
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**
```

For any other library you can see this link for further proguard operations
https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets

Answer (score 5):

Probably its better to add Okio rules from android-proguard-snippets:

```
# Okio
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**
```