# Not able to generate Signed APk after set minifyEnabled true

Tags: android, apk, retrofit, android-proguard

I have enable `minifyEnabled` to true but after that i am not able to generate signed apk.

It shows warning and error:

```
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced method 'boolean isDefault()' in library class java.lang.reflect.Method
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:there were 27 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

Now when i have set minifyEnabled to false then it will allow me to generate signed apk but i want to set set it to true.

How can i solved this ?

Comment: Please see as to how are you configuring your Proguard as to if any library is causing an issue. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589318/error-building-apk-when-minifyenabled-true

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with okio and proguard.

Follow [this link](https://github.com/square/okio/issues/60) for detailed explanation
But in short, it seems like you need to add those lines to proguard-rules file in your project.

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
```

Comment: Also see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737073/how-to-fix-warning-cant-find-referenced-class-in-android-eclipse-proguard-rul/37745414#37745414

Comment: i have defined :

`-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8` 

but after this all error solved but application is not able to called any functions

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in proguard-rules file:

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
```

[Reference](https://github.com/airbnb/native-navigation/issues/97)

Comment: i have defined :

`-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8` 

but after this all error solved but application is not able to called any functions.