# Cannot build release apk with proguard

Tags: android, gradle, build, proguard

Cannot build release apk with proguard. Without proguard all going great. I've tried many other rules for proguard that I found on the internet, but unsuccessfully. I have a suspicion that the problem is that I use VectorDrawable and minApi 19.

[image: Gradle output]

```
    -ignorewarnings

    # Remove logs
    -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
        public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
        public static int v(...);
        public static int i(...);
        public static int w(...);
        public static int d(...);
        public static int e(...);
    }

    # BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper
    -keep class com.chad.library.adapter.** {
        *;
    }
    -keep public class * extends com.chad.library.adapter.base.BaseQuickAdapter
    -keep public class * extends com.chad.library.adapter.base.BaseViewHolder
    -keepclassmembers public class * extends com.chad.library.adapter.base.BaseViewHolder {
        (android.view.View);
    }

    # Glide specific rules #
    -keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
    -keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.AppGlideModule
    -keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
        **[] $VALUES;
        public *;
    }

    # Realm
    -keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule
    -keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
    -keep class io.realm.internal.Keep
    -keep @io.realm.internal.Keep class *
    -dontwarn javax.**
    -dontwarn io.realm.**

    # Retrofit 2.X
    -dontwarn retrofit2.**
    -keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
    -keepattributes Signature
    -keepattributes Exceptions
    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        @retrofit2.http.* ;
    }
    -dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8

    # OkHttp
    -keepattributes Signature
    -keepattributes *Annotation*
    -keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
    -keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
    -dontwarn okhttp3.**

    # Okio
    -dontwarn okio.**
    -dontwarn org.codehaus.**
    -dontwarn java.nio.**
    -dontwarn java.lang.invoke.**
    -dontwarn rx.**
```

Android studio 3.0 Beta 2

Graddle version 4.1

Comment: I am not sure but try to change the Gradle version. do it lower

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737073/how-to-fix-warning-cant-find-referenced-class-in-android-eclipse-proguard-rul try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the path to proguard-rules

Changed this piece of code

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), '$project.rootDir/tools/proguard-rules.pro'
```

To this

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), '../tools/proguard-rules.pro'
```