# Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found while generating signed apk in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

There's a pro-guard rule inside `proguard-rules.pro` file as:

```
-keepresourcexmlelements manifest/application/meta-data@value=GlideModule
```

I removed that line as mentioned by someone [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1331#issuecomment-243689501).

Then again I got an error as:

> can't find referenced class
>   org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

Then I tried this code mentioned by someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37745414/9211918).

After Trying the mentioned code there's now another error as:

```
Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.auh$a.a(long, byte)`
Message{kind=WARNING, text=Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.auh$a.a(long, byte)`, sources=[D:\Wallprix\Wallprix\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\0.jar], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Please help me to fix this error as I don't know what should I implement now.

Details:

1. I'm using Glide Module
2. I've implemented Admob Interstitial code
3. Getting error while generating signed APK but not when testing App
   on a real device.

Comment: add your gradle file

Comment: @MilanPansuriya please check here: https://justpaste.it/7ii4u

Comment: did you fix it? i match the same error too

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Updating `firebase-core` from `17.0.0` to `17.2.0` fixed it for me.
Make sure that Your io.fabric is up to date with all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue just downgrade all your firebase and Google libary to 15.0.0 or If you have the perfect match in your firebase libary,  like everything having the same number